# Dynamically assigning classes in Qwik

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, qwik

I am new to Qwik and trying to conditionally add/remove classes from items in my navbar component. The complication is that I'm using tailwind and I want to conditionally add/remove the tailwind class (using custom animations), but it seems to have no effect. I have read about doing something like this in React using `clsx`, but this doesn't appear to be available in Qwik. Is there any way to dynamically add the tailwind class or how else can I achieve the same result?

Component

```
import { $, component$, useStore } from '@builder.io/qwik';
import { Link } from '@builder.io/qwik-city';

export const Navigation = component$(() => {

  const baseClass = "py-2 bg-white text-black w-[100px]";

  const menuItems = useStore([
    { label: "Home", value: "/", class: baseClass },
    { label: "About", value: "/about", class: baseClass },
    { label: "Contact Us", value: "/contact", class: baseClass },
  ]);

  const fadeout = $((num: number) => {
    menuItems.forEach((ele, i) => {
      if(i < num && !ele.class.includes("animate-fadeout")) {
      ele.class = baseClass + " animate-fadeout";
      }
    })
  });

  const fadein = $((num: number) => {
    menuItems.forEach((ele, i) => {
      if(i < num && ele.class.includes("animate-fadeout")) {
      ele.class = baseClass + " animate-fadein";
      }
    })
  });

  return (
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2 py-2 bg-slate-500">
      {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
        <Link className={item.class} key={index} onMouseOver$={() => fadeout(index)} onMouseOut$={() => fadein(index)} href={item.value}>{item.label}</Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
});
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        fadein: {
          '0%': { transform: 'translateY(-175%)', opacity: '0'},
          '10%': { transform: 'translateY(-150%)', opacity: '1'},
          '50%': { transform: 'translateY(0)'}
        },
        fadeout: {
          '50%': { transform: 'translateY(-175%)', opacity: '0'},
          '40%': { transform: 'translateY(-150%)', opacity: '1'},
          '0%': { transform: 'translateY(0)'}
        }
      },
      animation: {
        fadeout: 'fadeout 1s ease-in-out 1',
        fadein: 'fadein 1s ease-in-out 1',
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: Why is it className? I thought in qwik it was just the 'class' .

Comment: @Jay I tried `class` and `className` trying to find what worked. This was just my most recent attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `{deep: true}` as the options on your call to useStore. This will make the signaling work.

Also take a look at [qwik-transition](https://github.com/voluntadpear/qwik-transition) if you want to do transitions like this.

Furthermore, can't you use :hover to achieve what you want?

Finally, I would make a MenuItem component$ instead of composing everything in Navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll have to try it out when I have more time. I can't use `:hover` because what I'm trying to achieve is when a menu item is hovered, I want the items above it to fade in/out and not the hovered item. I hadn't come across anything about qwik-transition before, I'll be sure to check that out.

Comment: @calvinp Maybe you can use sibling selectors to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using classlist:

```
import { component$, useStore } from '@builder.io/qwik';
import { Link } from '@builder.io/qwik-city';

type ItemMode = 'fadein' | 'fadeout';

export const Navigation = component$(() => {
  const menuItems = useStore<
    { label: string; value: string; mode: ItemMode }[]
  >(
    [
      { label: 'Home', value: '/', mode: 'fadein' },
      { label: 'About', value: '/about', mode: 'fadein' },
      { label: 'Contact Us', value: '/contact', mode: 'fadein' }
    ],
    { deep: true }
  );

  return (
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2 py-2 bg-slate-500">
      {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
        <Link
          class={[
            'py-2 bg-white text-black w-[100px]',
            {
              'animate-fadeout': item.mode === 'fadeout',
              'animate-fadein': item.mode === 'fadein'
            }
          ]}
          key={index}
          onMouseOver$={() => {
            menuItems[index].mode = 'fadeout';
          }}
          onMouseOut$={() => {
            menuItems[index].mode = 'fadein';
          }}
          href={item.value}
        >
          {item.label}
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});
```